# How can I animate flexbox wrap in React w/o JQuery?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-animations

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504619/adding-animation-to-flex-wrap) covers how to use `jQuery` to accomplish this, but I'd like to avoid that as a) I don't know `jQuery` and b) my `React` project doesn't include it.

I have a `flexbox` container of elements, each of which has a `width` of either `x` or `4*x`, depending on a `boolean` variable in state.

When the `width` changes, the animation is pretty smooth, and it does push other elements as it grows.

But, each time an element reaches the border of the `div` & wraps to the next row, the animation stutters.

[Here's a codepen to illustrate.](https://codepen.io/brandonmp/pen/YWmAvj) (it's using `React` as I'm unsure how to replicate this in vanilla css/html/js)

Is there a way to animate the transition of an element from one line to the next?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32504619/3597276

Comment: have you tried using the jquery solution from the post you mentioned, but rewtire it to pure JS ?

Comment: No I haven't--it looks like there are a few ways to reliably check of a div has been resized, tho, so I might look into this approach. Something like, div resize event happens, each element checks its position to determine if it's about to wrap, and animates itself if it is. This might be tricky to do but feasible. Hoping there's something more simple, though, since this is just a cosmetic feature for my project.