# Add animation on wrap in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, components

i am learning react and i create flex box with 6 child containers with wrap property and i want to add animation on wrap.

i tried adding transition animation property in flex box but it's not working.

i don't know how to do it any one can help me please?

here is the code and live working demo link

https://codesandbox.io/live/7fe99a09b93

here is the Code:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className="flex_box">
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
        <div className="child_Containers"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the CSS:

```
.flex_box {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child_Containers {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
}
```

Comment: Your example link requires authentication, I don't thin many people are really willing to do that, sorry - including myself :)

Comment: Also this really really sounds like it actually has nothing to do with React, this sounds like regular HTML/CSS to me, so you could just make a demo with that. I would love to help, but I have no idea what you mean by `flex box with 6 child containers with wrap property and i want to add animation on wrap` which is why I needed to look at the example.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a workaround with JavaScript. Search for "flex-wrap animation" and you'll find examples like [adding animation to flex-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504619/adding-animation-to-flex-wrap)

Unfortunately `flex-wrap` is not animateable; it has `Animation type:   discrete` [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#formal_definition)

And in the [actual spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations/#animation-type) it says

> discrete: The property’s values cannot be meaningfully combined